# Monolog - logging only specific level of errors

Tags: php, monolog

I am using Monolog in vanilla PHP application.

I'd like to log errors of only specific level - INFO and **not above**, since I have other handlers for that.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$logger = new Logger('mylogger');
$logger->pushHandler(new StreamHandler(__DIR__.'/log/errors.log', Logger::WARNING));
$logger->pushHandler(new StreamHandler(__DIR__.'/log/info.log', Logger::INFO));
```

Is there any way to log just INFO mesages to `info.log`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same issue today which brought me to here. Anyway I solved it by using Monologs [FilterHandler](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Handler/FilterHandler.php).

The FilterHandler allows you to pass in another handler as an argument, and then specify the min and max logging levels that will trigger that handler.

There are a [few other handlers](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/doc/02-handlers-formatters-processors.md#handlers-formatters-and-processors) that can be useful in specific situations.

```
// Create the logging instance
$logger = new \Monolog\Logger('myLogger');

// Create error stream handler for error events and higher
$errorStreamHandler = new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler(
    'Some/DirectoryPath/error.log',
    \Monolog\Logger::ERROR);

// Create info stream handler for info events and higher
$infoStreamHandler = new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler(
    'Some/DirectoryPath/Info.log',
    \Monolog\Logger::INFO);

// Create filter handler to make sure info stream only logs info events
// Pass in the info handler 
// Debug is the minimum level this handler will handle
// Info is the maximum level this handler will handle
$infoFilterHandler = new \Monolog\Handler\FilterHandler(
    $infoStreamHandler,
    \Monolog\Logger::DEBUG,
    \Monolog\Logger::INFO);

// Add the handlers to logger
$logger->pushHandler($errorStreamHandler);
$logger->pushHandler($infoFilterHandler);

// Yay no errors in Info.log
$logger->addError("Some Error");
$logger->addInfo("Some Info");
```

**Update Ali**
Refer to the [source code](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Level.php) of \Monolog\Level to look up what constants are available then assign the constant to a variable.

```
$someVar = \Monolog\Level::Info;

$infoStreamHandler = new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler(
    'Some/DirectoryPath/Info.log',
    $someVar);
```

Comment: other (more explicit) way would be: `$infoFilterHandler = new \Monolog\Handler\FilterHandler($infoStreamHandler, [\Monolog\Logger::INFO]);`

Comment: How can I use a variable to define the log level in the mentioned code?

Comment: To clarify @MiguelPynto's comment, FilterHandler's second parameter accepts either a single value as the MINIMUM logging level, or a list of explicit levels that the handler will ONLY handle.

Answer (score 4):

Set `bubble` param to `false`

```
$logger->pushHandler(new StreamHandler(__DIR__.'/log/info.log', Logger::INFO, false));
```

Comment: This is actually the best answer

Answer (score 4):

### Option 1: Using the `bubble` parameter

Assuming your system only generates `INFO` and `ERROR` level messages (or more precisely, has handlers for each log level generated), the simplest way to accomplish sending the messages to the correct handlers is to set up your handler stack in the proper order and use the `bubble` parameter in the handler's constructor:

```php
$logger = new \Monolog\Logger('ChannelName');

// Note that higher-level messages are higher in the stack (added last)
$logger->pushHandler(new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler(
    LOG_DIR.'info.log',
    \Monolog\Logger::INFO
));
$logger->pushHandler(new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler(
    LOG_DIR.'error.log',
    \Monolog\Logger::ERROR,
    false // Prevents messages from bubbling 'up' the handler stack
));

$logger->info('Test info message.'); // Only sent to info.log
$logger->error('Test error message.'); // Only sent to error.log
```

Remember that stacks are processed as 'Last In First Out', so the last item added to the stack is the first item processed. Because the log level is the minimum level the handler will process, the handlers should be added to the stack ordered from lowest to highest.

The `bubble` parameter, which is `true` by default, indicates whether the message should be propagated to the rest of the handlers in the stack (**NOT** the log levels as described in another answer). By setting it to `false` in the code above, after the error handler processes the message the rest of the stack is not called.

### Option 2: Using the `FilterHandler` wrapper

The above works just fine, provided that you have handlers for every log level generated by your system. But what if that wasn't the case? For example, what if you wanted the error log to capture anything at level `ERROR` and above, but you also wanted a handler that would only process level `ALERT` for something exclusive, like sending email notices?

Monolog's [FilterHandler](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/main/src/Monolog/Handler/FilterHandler.php) is a wrapper that lets you specify what log levels a handler will receive. You can specify a range of levels from a minimum to maximum values, or a list of explicit levels.

Its constructor takes the following parameters:

| Parameter | Type | Description | Default |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $handler | callable | HandlerInterface | Handler or factory callable($record|null, $filterHandler) |
| $minLevelOrList | int|array | A list of levels to accept or a minimum level if maxLevel is provided | `Logger::DEBUG` |
| $maxLevel | int|string | Maximum level to accept, only used if $minLevelOrList is not an array | `Logger::EMERGENCY` |
| $bubble | bool | Whether the messages that are handled can bubble up the stack or not | true |

To use it, we simply add it to the top of our handler stack:

```php
$logger = new \Monolog\Logger('ChannelName');

// Note that higher-level messages are higher in the stack (added last)
$logger->pushHandler(new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler(
    LOG_DIR.'info.log',
    \Monolog\Logger::INFO
));
$logger->pushHandler(new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler(
    LOG_DIR.'error.log',
    \Monolog\Logger::ERROR,
    false // Prevents messages from bubbling up the handler stack
));
// Use FilterHandler to only pass certain messages to a handler
$logger->pushHandler(new \Monolog\Handler\FilterHandler(
    new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler(LOG_DIR.'alerts.log'), // Handler to receive filtered messages
    [\Monolog\Logger::ALERT] // Explicit list only contains ALERT
));


$logger->info('Test info message.'); // Sent to info.log only
$logger->error('Test error message.'); // Sent to error.log
$logger->alert('Test alert message.'); // Sent to alerts.log and error.log
$logger->emergency('Test emergency message.'); // Sent to error.log
```

Note the following:

- The target handler's log level was not set, leaving it at the default `Logger::DEBUG` since `FilterHandler` will control what level messages it receives.
- Bubbling was left at the default `true` so that the rest of the stack is called.
- The `Logger::ALERT` was passed as an array so that it would be treated as an explicit item rather than the minimum level so that `EMERGENCY` messages would not get sent to `alerts.log`.

One last thing: There are [many other handlers](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/main/doc/02-handlers-formatters-processors.md#handlers) that come with Monolog for doing specialty processing such as email. I just used `StreamHandler` as the target handler for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Sasha Vas answer.

Monologs StreamHandler has a bubble parameter which does exactly what you want, avoids the log bubbling up to other levels.

After Laravel `5.6` this undocumented feature is also available.

This is how one of my `channels` looks like:

```
'warning' => [
            'driver' => 'single',
            'level' => 'warning',
            'bubble' => false,
            'path' => storage_path('logs/warning.log'),
],
```

Now, if I use `Log::warning('warning')` it will only show up in `warning.log`