# how to write info, errors, warnings, emergency errors to different files instead of laravel.log

Tags: laravel

Basically, I have this right now in logging.php

```
 'daily' => [
            'driver' => 'daily',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
            'level' => 'debug',
            'days' => 14,
        ],
```

but what this will do is everytime i write any kind of errors(emergency, debug, info or whatever), all errors will be written in this file.

What I need is to split different kind of error types to different kind of files and also all of these must use daily. Here will be the final structure I need.

```
\storage
            \logs
                \info
                    laravel-24-04-18.log
                    laravel-25-04-18.log
                \error
                    laravel-24-04-18.log
                    laravel-25-04-18.log

                \emergency
                    laravel-24-04-18.log
                    laravel-25-04-18.log
```

I have searched too much. I found so many solutions, but since then laravel changed so much that no solution has worked yet for me. I'm using 5.7 laravel.

Answer (score 0):

## Explaination

From reading your question I'm thinking you'll need different logging channels for each separate log file you want written. The only issue with that is that you can only specify the minimum log level when configuring a logging channel. In your case it's set to `debug` meaning anything with debug level or higher will be sent through to the channel.

Example from laravel docs:

```
'channels' => [
    'stack' => [
        'driver' => 'stack',
        'channels' => ['syslog', 'slack'],
    ],

    'syslog' => [
        'driver' => 'syslog',
        'level' => 'debug',
    ],

    'slack' => [
        'driver' => 'slack',
        'url' => env('LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL'),
        'username' => 'Laravel Log',
        'emoji' => ':boom:',
        'level' => 'critical',
    ],
],
```

> Given our configuration, the syslog channel will write the message to the system log; however, since the error message is not critical or above, it will not be sent to Slack. However, if we log an emergency message, it will be sent to both the system log and Slack since the emergency level is above our minimum level threshold for both channels

## Solution 1

A solution to your issue would be to write to configure multiple logging channels and write to each of them directly like so:

```
Log::channel('slack')->info('Something happened!');
```

This way the log messages will not end up in channels, other than the one it's sent to.

## Solution 2

Alternatively you could add a FilterHandler to each channel, which will allow you to specify a minimum and a maximum log level.

More information on configuring a channel handler can be found here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/logging#creating-monolog-handler-channels.

Information on setting up a FilterHandler can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52310813/7528944